# NSStatusItem reordering along Status Bar

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I am trying to add a functionality to my status bar app for Mac OS X. I would like to be able to move my item along the bar, as you can do for the native OS tools like the Bluetooth or the WiFi icon.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `NSMenuExtra` and not `NSMenuItem`.

Apple uses `NSMenuExtra` for the system menu icons including Wi-Fi and Bluetooth. Although it looks similar to the regular `NSMenuItem`, `NSMenuExtra` has some special features, notably to keep their relative order after rebooting, and Command-Draggable by user.

Unfortunately, `NSMenuExtra` is totally undocumented, so if you are targeting the Mac App Store, it's better for you to stick with the standard `NSMenuItem`. Otherwise, there is a bunch of tutorials about how to create an `NSMenuExtra`. For example, here are two of them:

- [NSMenuExtra – working with undocumented APIs](https://duhanebel.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/nsmenuextra-how-to-work-with-undocumented-apis/)
- [Building NSMenuExtra - A Small Tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000078.php)

Answer (score 2):

**Update for macOS Sierra**: Apple improved `NSStatusItem`. Items can now be reordered by ⌘-dragging. This works for all Apple’s menu items and all third party apps.

Pretty much all the reasons you could ever want to use `NSMenuExtra` have been removed now, which is great. So, the answer now is to just use `NSStatusItem`. No further action is required.

Comment: In my experience reordering/dragging is still not supported in NSStatusItem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no 'good' way to do that, however you can check this question for the hack which can do that:

[How to drag NSStatusItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623852/how-to-drag-nsstatusitems)